# why is preview image not loading in SharePoint custom site design?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have created a site design, then tried to update previewImageUrl property with an image link. The property got updated correctly, but when I select the site design to create a site, the preview image is not being loaded.

Could you please help me on this?

`Set-SPOSiteDesign -Identity 01hgh233 -PreviewImageUrl "https://sitesharepoint.sharepoint/sites/test.png"`

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen site design accepts preview image URL from any site.

Try below trick it should for you.

1. Set PreviewImageUrl as empty so it should apply default image. use below script

   Set-SPOSiteDesign -Identity  -PreviewImageUrl ""
2. Once you see the default Preview image then using the same PowerShell command set the correct URL.

   Set-SPOSiteDesign -Identity  -PreviewImageUrl "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/DocumentLib/333.png"